# Ember.js peekAll not triggering foo.loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue where I'm using `peekAll()` to load a large list of records in my route model(). I've got some view rendering streamlining to do as the page render is currently taking 2500ms, but it's highlighting that the `foo.loading` state doesn't seem to be triggered, as the page template hangs on the existing link when the new link is clicked for the 2500ms without loading displaying. How do I manually control the `foo.loading` state in the route.js file so that the loading template renders?

I've got the following code in my route.js file currently trying to use `schedule` to set `isRendering` on the controller:

```
  model(params, transition) {
    const passedInOrgCode = transition.params.customers.org_code;
    const orgCode = passedInOrgCode !== undefined ? passedInOrgCode : this.get('currentUser.org.orgCode');

    if (orgCode !== this.get('currentUser.impersonatedOrg.orgCode')) {
      this.store.queryRecord('organisation', { org: orgCode }).then(org => {
        this.get('currentUser').impersonateOrg(org);
    }

    const peekData = this.store.peekAll('customer');

    let filterByOrg = (customers) => {
      return customers.filter((item) => {
        if (item.get('parentOrgCode') === orgCode || parseInt(orgCode) === ENV.APP.KORDIA_ORG_CODE) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    };

    if (peekData.get('content').length === 0) {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.store.query('customer', { orgCode: orgCode }).then((customers) => {
          resolve(filterByOrg(customers));
        }).catch(() => { reject(); });
      });
    } else {
      Ember.run(() => {
        this.controllerFor('customers.index').set('isRendering', true);
        return filterByOrg(peekData);
      });
      Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', () => {
        this.controllerFor('customers.index').set('isRendering', false);
      });
    }

  },
```

And in my handlebars file:

```
{{#if isRendering}}
  {{loading-component }}
  {{else}}
  {{customer-list customers=model updated=updated search=search orgCode=orgCode}}
{{/if}}
```

All of the states are triggering to the console with the right timing, but I can't get the view to render the loading state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I had to wrap my `peekAll` in a RSVP promise object with an `Ember.run.later` function. The answer was in the Asynchronous Routing docs - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_the-router-pauses-for-promises. The relevant piece of code is below:

```
if (peekData.get('content').length === 0) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.store.query('customer', { orgCode: orgCode }).then((customers) => {
      resolve(filterByOrg(customers));
    }).catch(() => { reject(); });
  });
} else {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    Ember.run.later(function() {
      resolve(filterByOrg(peekData));
    });
  });
}
```

Hope this helps someone :)